# AWS S3 ACL public-read-write: security concern

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i want some explain on AWS S3 ACL public-read-write, from the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html):

> Owner gets FULL_CONTROL. The AllUsers group gets READ and WRITE
>   access. Granting this on a bucket is generally not recommended.
>
> [...]
>
> All Users group – Represented by
>   http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers. Access permission to
>   this group allows anyone to access the resource. The requests can be
>   signed (authenticated) or unsigned (anonymous). Unsigned requests omit
>   the Authentication header in the request.

but this mean that every aws account can be read/write my files? or only my IAM user can read/write my files?

Comment: The above suggests that *anyone* can access the resources, as in *any* authenticated user on the whole of AWS. That's probably why it is "generally not recommended". You can always test it yourself by creating such a bucket and trying to access it as various different users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this document: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html

> Amazon S3 Predefined Groups
>
> Amazon S3 has a set of predefined groups. When granting account access
>   to a group, you specify one of our URIs instead of a canonical user
>   ID. We provide the following predefined groups:
>
> Authenticated Users group – Represented by
>   http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AuthenticatedUsers. This group
>   represents all AWS accounts. Access permission to this group allows
>   any AWS account to access the resource. However, all requests must be
>   signed (authenticated).
>
> All Users group – Represented by
>   http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers. Access permission to
>   this group allows anyone to access the resource. The requests can be
>   signed (authenticated) or unsigned (anonymous). Unsigned requests omit
>   the Authentication header in the request.
>
> Log Delivery group –
>   Represented by http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/s3/LogDelivery. WRITE
>   permission on a bucket enables this group to write server access logs
>   (see Server Access Logging) to the bucket.

With ACL, you just can share your S3 bucket with other AWS Accounts. Who without logged in AWS account, they cannot access your bucket.

If you want both AWS Account and non-AWS Account can access you S3 bucket, you must define S3 Bucket Policy.
For example:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::S3-Bucket-name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: this means that every users with an AWS's account, can delete/update the file?

Comment: other aws account can delete/update your file or not depend on your setting. You can set it as read permission or full permission

Comment: Go to S3, select your S3 bucket, click to Permission tab and you can see 4 option Access to the objects: `List objects`, `Write objects`, and  Access to this bucket's ACL: `Read bucket permissions`, `Write bucket permissions`.If you enable `read/write bucket permission` => full permission, other user can re-config your bucket ACL => to dangerous