# Accessing data stored in AWS S3 public bucket

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This is my first ever AWS work so the question below might be very easy for many but I need a bit of help.

When I go to `https://hello-world.s3-ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/`, I get response below in my browser.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ListBucketResult xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2007-01-01/">
    <Name>hello-world</Name>
    <Prefix></Prefix>
    <Marker></Marker>
    <MaxKeys>1000</MaxKeys>
    <IsTruncated>false</IsTruncated>
    <Contents>
        <Key>data-1.json</Key>
        <LastModified>2017-01-01T10:00:00.000Z</LastModified>
        <ETag>"1234567890qwertyui"</ETag>
        <Size>12345</Size>
        <StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass>
    </Contents>
</ListBucketResult>
```

Assume that this is a public S3 bucket. How can I get the data stored in `data-1.json` if I don't have the credentials (as far as I know I wouldn't need credentials for public buckets)? I went through the documentation and blog posts but couldn't find any example that doesn't use credentials.

I've come up with code below after checking https://github.com/awslabs/aws-php-sample but it also mentiones that I need credentils https://github.com/awslabs/aws-php-sample#basic-configuration

```
$s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'version' => '2007-01-01',
    'region'  => 'ca-central-1'
]);

$result = $s3->getObject([
    'Bucket' => 'hello-world',
    'Key'    => 'data-1.json'
]);

echo $result['Body'];
```

**Note:** I'll use be using Symfony framework.

Comment: try this one! https://stackoverflow.com/a/46400522/3471694

Comment: try: https://s3.amazonaws.com/hello-world/data-1.json or https://hello-world.s3.amazonaws.com/data-1.json

Comment: @Asdfg The second one worked. Thank you very much for that! Much appreciated.

Comment: Are there any examples to create new buckets, new object with key and deleting bucket/object so on?

Comment: here you go: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/examples/s3-examples-creating-buckets.html

Comment: I have seen it but it requires credentils as well.

Comment: What is your objective? Is it to to allow certain users access the object without making the bucket public?

Comment: My objective is to use public bucket without having credentials. The link I posted n my post above says I need credentials. Every example and the official doc states I need credentials to use S3 Client.